# Maps Direction Line doesn't showing up on Maps

Tags: ios, swift, api, google-maps, direction

On trying to give direction line between User location to defined location. The pinpoints were right and exactly at the desired location but there is no 'Line' direction which leads User location to defined location.

It was done like this image:

[image]

and my code for drawing the maps along with parsing google maps API JSON:

```
func DrawDirection(url: String, cord: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    request(url).responseJSON { response in
        let parsed = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
        let routes = parsed!["routes"] as! [[String:Any]]
        for route in routes {
            let dictArr = route["legs"] as? [[String:Any]]
            let dict = dictArr![0]["steps"] as? [[String:Any]]
            let start = dict![0]["start_location"] as? [String:Any]
            let lat = start!["lat"] as! Double
            let long = start!["lng"] as! Double
            let dotcoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(long))
            let routePoly = route["overview_polyline"] as! [String:Any]
            let points = routePoly["points"] as! String
            let line = points
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: cord, coordinate: dotcoordinate)
                let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsetsMake(170, 30, 30, 30))
                self.CinemaLoc.moveCamera(update)
            }
            self.AddingPolyLine(encString: line, dir: cord, dot: dotcoordinate)
        }
    }
}

func AddingPolyLine(encString: String, dir: CLLocationCoordinate2D, dot: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    let dotpath: GMSMutablePath = GMSMutablePath()
    dotpath.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(dir.latitude, dir.longitude)) //original loc
    dotpath.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(dot.latitude, dot.longitude)) //starting points
    let dotpoly = GMSPolyline(path: dotpath)
    dotpoly.map = self.CinemaLoc
    dotpoly.strokeWidth = 3.0
    let styles:[Any] = [GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.blue), GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.clear)]
    let lengths:[Any] = [10,5]
    dotpoly.spans = GMSStyleSpans(dotpoly.path!,styles as! 
[GMSStrokeStyle], lengths as! [NSNumber], GMSLengthKind.rhumb)
    let poly = GMSPolyline(path: dotpath)
    poly.strokeWidth = 3.0
    poly.strokeColor = .red
    poly.map = self.CinemaLoc
}
```

`cord` is User location

been trying all possible way on stack overflow but not getting any change and sometimes there are log saying "Failed to load optimized model at path ~/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/"

is there any wrong with my code?

Comment: in the for loop, `for route in routes` you just get the `route.polylinePath` and put to your drawFunction. `AddingPolyLine `.

Comment: yes, that's what I got from several practices. is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Path should be created only once, for a specific path, and then you can add coordinates to the path. You're doing wrong by putting `let dotpath: GMSMutablePath = GMSMutablePath()` inside your method call, which gets called for every loop.

Comment: Also `poly` , `dotPoly` and other polyline properties should should be outside the for loop. And I think you got the whole idea wrongly. Inside the for loop where you get coordinates, you should be adding coordinates to the path, not declaring neither path nor polylines here. Polyline should be configured after you are done adding coordinates to path. Try this way and tell me.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, after some checking, the problem is on my url. been fixed now and the line is show. and yes about loop, that does not really matter since gmaps api give ouput only one array for that

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, problem fixed. there are misplaced on my url. and for adding polyline should be like this

```
let path = GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: "String from overview json")
let poly = GMSPolyline(path: dotpath)
poly.strokeWidth = 3.0
poly.strokeColor = .red
poly.map = self.CinemaLoc
```

On routes loop, it should be no problem since google maps api only give 1 array of route, but for better practice. It should out of loop

Thank you and happy coding!